Entity Framework Core : issue when dynamically updating entities using model builder
I'm currently trying to develop a central app with addons. Central app stores the core entities (like AppEntity, AppRole, Device, ...). It has its own DBContext.
I would like to add some entities when importing addons. For example I would like to add an entity (and its related table in database) during module import.
In the module I created a class implementing IEntityTypeConfiguration<BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector> : OK
public class BitLockerVolumeKeyProtectorConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector> builder)
    {
        builder.HasNoKey();
        builder.Property( t => t.KeyProtectorId ).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.MountPoint).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.RecoveryPassword).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.CreationDate).IsRequired();
        builder.HasOne("Device");

        builder.ToTable("BitLockerVolumeKeyProtectors");
    }
}

In the application, I've create an addon Service which is in charge of loading Dll : OK
public class AddOnService : IAddOnService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly List<IAddOn> _addons = new List<IAddOn>();

    public AddOnService(ILogger<AddOnService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task LoadAddonsAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Start Loading Addons");

        _addons.Clear();
        var test = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var addonAssemblies = Directory.GetFiles($"{test}\\Addons", "*.dll");

        if (addonAssemblies.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var assemblyPath in addonAssemblies)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Start Loading Addon [{assemblyPath}]");

                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
                var addonTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IAddOn).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface);

                if (addonTypes.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var type in addonTypes)
                    {
                        var addon = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IAddOn;

                        if (addon != null)
                        {
                            _addons.Add(addon);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"No Addon to load");
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task RegisterEntitiesAsync(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var addon in _addons)
        {
            await addon.RegisterEntitiesAsync(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public async Task SeedDataAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        foreach (var addon in _addons)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Start Seeding data for Addon [{addon.Name}]");
            await addon.SeedDataAsync(serviceProvider);
        }
    }
}

In the application, I've created a DatabaseInitializer which is in charge of updating Dbcontext by importing any class implementing IEntityTypeConfiguration<> from any loaded addon. This operation is performed by using modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly().
public class DatabaseInitializer
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly IApplicationDBContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IAddOnService _addOnService;

    public DatabaseInitializer(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IApplicationDBContext>();
        _addOnService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAddOnService>();
    }

    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        await _dbContext.ReconfigureModelAsync();

        await _addOnService.SeedDataAsync(_serviceProvider);
    }
}

public class BitLockerManagement : IAddOn
{
    public Guid Id => Guid.Parse("9d877d65-96bd-474d-ae20-45873f51a2f4");

    public string Name => "BitLocker Management";

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Roles> AddonRoles => Roles.List;

    public async Task RegisterEntitiesAsync(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(this.GetType().Assembly);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task SeedDataAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = serviceProvider.GetService<IApplicationDBContext>();
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<AppRole>>();

        // Inject Module Roles 
        //using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        //{
        //    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IApplicationDBContext>();
        //    var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<AppRole>>();

            // Inject Addons AppRoles
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Roles> role in AddonRoles)
            {
                if (!context.AppRoles.Any(r => r.Name == role.Key))
                {
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(AppRole.CreateInstance(role.Key, role.Value.Description));
                }
            }

            // Test creating RecoveryPasswordRecord
            var device = context.Devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.SerialNumber == "5CG1263PK8");

            if (device != null)
            {
                var recoveryPasswordInformation = BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector.CreateRecoveryPasswordInstance(device, "90595464-9272-472F-A8FD-3ECD070F5BAF", "431761-571725-276870-448547-187220-398805-243375-347688", "C:");

                await (context as DbContext).AddAsync<BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector>(recoveryPasswordInformation);

                //await (context as DbContext).Set<BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector>()
                //    .AddAsync(recoveryPasswordInformation);

                //var tpmPinInformation = BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector.CreateTPMPinInstance(device, "425E47A9-1A74-46B3-888D-54282D0BFC71", "0662007682", "C:");
                //await (context as DbContext).Set<BitLockerVolumeKeyProtector>()
                //    .AddAsync(tpmPinInformation);
                await (context as DbContext).SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        //}
    }
}

At the end of DatabaseInitialization (especially  I can see that a new Entity has been added to dbContext.Model property.
My problem occurs when calling _dbcontext.ReconfigureModelAsync(). This method is defined in my DBContext :
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext, IApplicationDBContext
{
    private readonly IAddOnService _addonService;

    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions options, IAddOnService addOnService) 
        : base(options)
    {
        _addonService = addOnService;
    }

    public DbSet<AppRole> AppRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AppEntityBase> AppEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    
    protected override async void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppEntityBase>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
            .HasValue<ClientApp>("ClientApp")
            .HasValue<ADUser>("ADUser")
            .HasValue<ADGroup>("ADGroup");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ADBasedEntity>()
            .HasIndex(u => u.LoginName)
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ADBasedEntity>()
            .Property(p => p.Sid)
            .HasColumnName("Sid");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ADBasedEntity>()
            .HasIndex(u => u.Sid)
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder.Entity<AppEntityBase>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
            .WithMany(e => e.Users)
            .UsingEntity<Entity_Role>("AppEntities_AppRoles");

        await modelBuilder.ApplyAddonEntitiesAsync(_addonService);
    }

    public async Task ReconfigureModelAsync()
    {
        var modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder( new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConventionSet() );

        OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        //await modelBuilder.ApplyAddonEntitiesAsync(_addonService);
    }

    public override IModel Model => base.Model;
}

At the end of OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder), I can see the new entity added to the model, but once outside of OnModelCreating, the entity is no more part of entities.
Do you have any idea?
Thank you in advance

In the normal run of events, the OnModelCreating method gets called by EF with an instance of ModelBuilder that is used to construct its own internal models.
Your method is creating a new instance of ModelBuilder, rather than using the one that is used during the construction of the context.
The problem here, is that you are then not actually using this to build a model, and the one used during the initialisation is long gone.
EF's internal context model is created only during intialisation, and it is at this point that you should be determining what entities your context contains.
You should be doing this by injecting a context factory into your class that consumes the context, rather than a context, and you can use this to create the context instance. The context factory would be the natural place to override the behaviour that determines which entities are in your specific context instance.

Thank you so much Ed, you saved me hours of googling !
you're absolutely right.
I changed my way to initialize services :

Addons Are now loaded before ApplicationDBContext service Created.
In ApplicationDBContext OnModelCreating() method, addon service (which is injected in ApplicationDBContext) is able to retrieve any IEntityTypeConfiguration and apply changes.

Next step : Apply Migrations for each addons in order to save information in database.
Have a nice day
